# How to set current date in kendo ui datepicker date view calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working with **kendo UI**. I had to write small code snippets to perform certain tasks like, I have two **kendo Date Picker** in which suppose i have select first date-picker date , and when i click on second date-picker, how to `set calendar view highlight date (default it is current date)` which was previously selected date in first.

Code is like below:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {               
             var sessionDate=new Date();
                 $("#datepickerFrom").kendoDatePicker({                  
                   change:function() {
                    if(this.value()!=null)
                    {
                      sessionDate=this.value();
                    }

                  }
                });
              $("#datepickerTo").kendoDatePicker({
                  open: function() {
                    if(this.value()==null)
                    {                                       
                      var calendar = this.dateView.calendar;
                      calendar.current(sessionDate);
                    }
                  }
                });
            });
```

> I want to highlight sessionDate in dateview

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples:

1. Set the date of datepicker2 on change of datepicker1
2. Set the date of datepicker3 ONLY on open of datepicker3

Both values are taken from datepicker1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sessionDate;
  // create DatePicker from input HTML element
  $("#datepicker1").kendoDatePicker({
    change: function() {
      sessionDate = this.value()
      $("#datepicker2").data("kendoDatePicker").value(sessionDate);
    }
  });
  $("#datepicker2").kendoDatePicker();
  $("#datepicker3").kendoDatePicker({
    open: function() {
      this.value(sessionDate)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div class="demo-section k-content">

    <h4>Datepicker 1:</h4>
    <input id="datepicker1" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />

    <h4>Datepicker 2 (set value on change of datepicker1):</h4>
    <input id="datepicker2" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />

    <h4>Datepicker 3 (set value on open):</h4>
    <input id="datepicker3" value="10/10/2011" style="width: 100%" />
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</div>
```